# Make table of contents fit in sidebar - beamer

Tags: beamer, sidebar

I am having trouble with my sidebar in beamer. I'm using the PaloAlto theme, and have too many sections & subs, so it's running out of the frame. I have read that I can reduce fontsize, was wondering if there's a way to reduce space between each section title too? when the sidebar is predefined in a theme. thanks!

edit - here's the (shortened) preamble code and a picture of the problem:

```
    \documentclass[pdftex, mathserif/mathsans, red]{beamer}

    \usetheme{PaloAlto}


    \usecolortheme{beaver}

    \setbeamercolor*{title in sidebar}{fg=darkred!50!black}
    \setbeamercolor*{author in sidebar}{fg=darkgray}
    \setbeamercolor*{section in sidebar}{fg=gray}
    \setbeamercolor*{subsection in sidebar}{fg=gray}


    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \mode<presentation>


    \begin{document}
```

[image: Slide example]

You can see the titles in the sidebar exceeding the space.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question?

Comment: thanks @leandriis! hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

- you can change the font size of the sections in the sidebar with `\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\Tiny}`
- to change the vertical spacing, you can redefine the `section in sidebar` and `section in sidebar shaded` templates like this:

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\setbeamercolor*{title in sidebar}{fg=darkred!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{author in sidebar}{fg=darkgray}
\setbeamercolor*{section in sidebar}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{subsection in sidebar}{fg=gray}


\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\mode<presentation>

\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\Tiny}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip-5ex% <- was 1ex by default
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar}{\insertsectionhead}%
  }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip-5ex% <- was 1ex by default
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar shaded}{\insertsectionhead}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]